# Python 3 Jump Tables

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to create a basic jump table, so I can better understand different ways of creating menus in Python 3.5.6. Here is what I have so far:

```
def command():
    selection = input("Please enter your selection: ")
    return selection

def one():
    print ("you have selected menu option one")

def two():
    print ("you have selected menu option two")

def three():
    print ("you have selected menu option three")

def runCommand(command):
    jumpTable = 0
    jumpTable[command]()
    jumpTable = {}
    jumpTable['1'] = one
    jumpTable['2'] = two
    jumpTable['3'] = three

def main():
    command()
    runCommand(command)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As far as I understand, a jump table is simply a way of making a menu selection and calling a specific function associated with that numerical value, taken in by my "command" function. Within the jumpTable, you assign the function to call.

I am getting " File "omitted", line 16, in runCommandjumpTableone
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

All I want to do is have the user enter a number - 1, 2 or 3 and have that function run. when I get this basic functionality down, I will expand the menu to show the options and be more clear. I just need to get the darn thing to run!

Yes, I am aware of other ways to create menus (IF/ELIF/ELSE) I am just trying to nail this one down!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You initialize jumptable to 1 instead of a container , then try to index it. As the error already said, that is not valid. You have to properly build your jump table *before* using it.

Comment: There are so many errors in this code I wouldn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite close. The only issue is that you are trying to access the command before creating the jumpTable. And I am also not sure why you are setting the variable to `0` first (that's why you get the `int` is not subscriptible error). So, this is the right order:

```
def runCommand(command):
    jumpTable = {}
    jumpTable['1'] = one
    jumpTable['2'] = two
    jumpTable['3'] = three
    jumpTable[command]()
```

By the way, if you are always creating the same `jumpTable`, you could create it once, outside the function and simply call `jumpTable[command]()` in your `main` function.

Another problem: you should store the value you get from the user and pass that to the next function like this:

```
cmd = command()
runCommand(cmd)
```

, or simply `pipe` the two functions together like this:

```
runCommand(command())
```

Comment: KeyError: <function command at 0x0000000001E15400> So now apparently it cannot find the key value, so it spits out a memory location... In the past, I would always build my dictionaries so I would know the value. In this case it seems it's built on the fly. I adjusted my code with what you said zsomko.

Comment: Your problem is now what I have described in the part after "Another problem" in my reply. You are trying to index your dictionary with the function named command, not the return value of that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Based on the original question, the following will.
Add a menu to a console application to manage activities.
Run a selected function.
Clear the output 
Display the menu again or exit if done is selected
"""
import sys
from os import system


def display_menu(menu):
    """
    Display a menu where the key identifies the name of a function.
    :param menu: dictionary, key identifies a value which is a function name
    :return:
    """
    for k, function in menu.items():
        print(k, function.__name__)


def one():
    print("you have selected menu option one")
    input("Press any Enter to return to menu.")
    system('cls') # clears stdout


def two():
    print("you have selected menu option two")
    input("Press any Enter to return to menu.")
    system('cls') # clears stdout


def three():
    print("you have selected menu option three")
    input("Press any Enter to return to menu.")
    system('cls') # clears stdout


def done():
    system('cls') # clears stdout
    print("Goodbye")
    sys.exit()


def main():
    # Create a menu dictionary where the key is an integer number and the
    # value is a function name.
    functions_names = [one, two, three, done]
    menu_items = dict(enumerate(functions_names, start=1))

    while True:
        display_menu(menu_items)
        selection = int(
            input("Please enter your selection number: "))  # Get function name
        selected_value = menu_items[selection] # Gets the function name
        selected_value()  # add parentheses to call the function


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```